# Implementing Generic Routines

Tags: programming-practices

Is it possible to implement generic routines in any language (C#, Java, etc). By generic routines I mean, in specific event Handlers. Lets say, I have 2 Buttons and 2 text boxes. One Button, when pressed, takes the first text box text and converts to Uppercase and second button prints the length of the string in the other text box. Now, Can I have a function as

```
button(type, textbox) {
if(type==1)
/*Convert to upper case*/
else if(type==2)
/*Print the length*/
}
```

The type takes any button as input and further processes it. I want to implement this because of redundancy in my code and I want to make my code portable to other languages. So that I need to modify only the syntax to make it work. Is it feasible?

Comment: This sort of thing is the least of your worries if you are going to port your code to different languages. Even porting to a different GUI framework in the *same* language is generally a huge job. Besides, having separate functions to do different things is a good idea, I don't know why you want to try to combine them into one function like this.

Comment: Yes, it is possible in any Turing-complete language.  But some languages and frameworks make this easier than others.  C# and Winforms has Event Handlers that pretty much give you this functionality out of the box.

Comment: Can you give an example how to implement this in C# @RobertHarvey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, this should be done by having one handler for each logic.

```
void handleUppercase(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    // convert text to uppercase
}

void handleLength(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    // display length
}

// then assign those handlers properly
button1.OnClick += handleUppercase
button2.OnClick += handleLength
```

Also, you are not going to have much luck changing code for different languages, because different languages use different UI frameworks. And there are too big differences between those frameworks to allow any kind of sharing. If you want to have same code in different languages, you have to make sure it doesn't depend on any specific framework. Which UI frameworks are.

The case is quite different when you have same logic, but on different buttons with different parameters. In this case, you have 2 basic options.

First is to use similar approach as Robert suggests:

```
void handleUppercase(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    if (sender == buttonA) // do logic for first arguments
    if (sender == buttonB) // do logic for second arguments
}
buttonA.OnClick += handleUppercase
buttonB.OnClick += handleUppercase
```

Second option is to parametrize the handler itself. In OOP, that could be done if the handler was a [Command](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern). Simply create different instances of command with different parameters for each button. In functional way, you could use [partial application](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_application). But because C# doesn't have this concept, you have to help yourself with lambdas:

```
void handleUppercase(object sender, EventArgs evArgs, Argument arg)
{
    // do logic for arg
}

buttonA.OnClick += (s, e) => { handleUppercase(s, e, arg1); }
buttonB.OnClick += (s, e) => { handleUppercase(s, e, arg2); }
```

Comment: @subhamsoni See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

In C#, it would look something like this:

```
// Loop through the controls on the form, and do something
// specific with each control, based on its type.
foreach (Control control in form.Controls)
{
    switch (control.GetType().Name)
    {
        case "TextBox":
            var textBox = (TextBox)control;
            // Do something with the text box
            break;
        case "ComboBox":
            var comboBox = (ComboBox)control;
            // Do something with the combo box
            break;
        case "CheckBox":
            var checkBox = (CheckBox)control;
            // Do something with the checkbox
            break;
    }
}
```

This code works because all Controls in Winforms inherit from a base Control class.